# What will happen to the ball in a vacuum container when suddenly the gravity after 2 seconds disappears?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, kinematics, velocity

Suppose that there is a ball in a vacuum container where mass of the ball is $2$ kg. The height of the container is $100$ m. Assume that the acceleration due to gravity is $10$ m per second square.

I was wondering, if I drop the ball from the top of the container and after $2$ sec, the gravity of the earth suddenly disappears, what will be the final velocity of the ball when it reaches the bottom of the container?

Will the ball ever stop in the container? If yes what will be that time from when the ball is dropped?
I mean will the ball apply force on the floor of the vacuum room or the container? If yes the floor should also apply an opposite and equal force by newton's third law.

Comment: The ball will stop when it reaches the other end of the container, of course. All it means for gravity to disappear is that the acceleration disappears. So you can split the fall into two parts: The motion during gravity and the motion without gravity. For each part you can set up a motion equation to figure out how far it comes and how fast a speed it reaches.

Comment: But the ceiling of the container should apply a force on the ball and then the ball should not stop.

Comment: The ceiling? How would the ceiling apply a force to the ball while it is falling in midair? Or are we talking about the ball bouncing off of the floor when it reaches the bottom? Could you please add a sketch of the scenario to make the situation clear?

Answer (score 2):

If the container is large enough the ball will be accelerated for 2 seconds then it will continue moving at a constant velocity until it hits the bottom, then, depending on the elasticity of the collisions, it may bounce from bottom to top and back a few times loosing kinetic energy to material deformations.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this answer can help you understanding a little bit better what's going on.
You can consider this type of falling as a rectilinear motion. Let's now introduce a reference system of a single axis (since the motion is rectilinear). We can place it by aligning its direction with the one of the acceleration vector $\vec{g}$ (in poor words the system will be perpendicular to the ground). Then the verse of this axe, for convenience should be fixed according to the verse of $\vec{g}$ (it points to the bottom). So the $\vec{g}$ has always modulus positive. Now as I said before the motion can be split into two different motions: the folling from the top for $2s$ (which is a uniform accelerated rectilinear motion) and the falling from the position in which it is when $2s$ have passed to the bottom of the vacuum room. So, if I have understand your question right, you want to know what is the velocity when the ball reaches the bottom. Hence, we can calculate the velocity after $2s$ (when the gravity doesn't persist anymore). So we can use the velocities formula:

$$v = v_0 + g \Delta t$$

(it isn't necessary to use the vectorial form for the velocity or the acceleration, since it concides with the refernce system axis and verse). We can consider that $v_0 = v(0s) = 0{m \over s}$. Therefore:

$$v(2s) = 9,8 {m \over s^2} 2s = 19,6 {m \over s} [= 2 \cdot 10 {m \over s}] $$

then, since no more force is present (as you said after $2s$ there is no more gravity), for the II principles of dynamic, no more acceleration is present. Then the rest of the motion is uniform rectilinear motion, so the velocity is constant and hence $v_f = v(2s) = 19,6 {m \over s}$. You, then, ask if the ground stops the falling of the object and the answer is yes. This because the force exerted by the floor to the falling object doesn't depends on the gravity.
I hope this was useful, but I didn't manage to understand the last question, if you can explain me what is your doubt I could help you more!

Comment: I edited my question where I explained my doubt again.